# PBKDF2 implementation within MS-SQL

Tags: encryption, hash, sql-server-2012

I have a requirementto automatically create some SQL data which will contain PBKDF2 encrypted data within it

I can see there are ways to implement this hash using CLR - is there anyway to implement it simply through SQL (T-SQL or stored procedures)? Environment restrictions do not lend themselves to allowing me to implement using CLR

Any help greatly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: What do you use the PBKDF2 for, is it to store passwords, is salting required?